# Starting Openssh with C# on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I am writing a program in C# on Ubuntu with Mono. This program takes files and PGP encrypts them, then SSH them to clients. I got the PGP to work by using Process.Start(gpg, arguments). My question is can I do the same with SSH, I have yet to find the SSH executable on Ubuntu to run. I want to do this to exclude using an API, like SharpSSH.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to eliminate the use of SharpSSH? I have a project that I am writing now that uses it so if you can shed some light on why you don't want to use it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This is just a preference. But APIs tend to lose support and break over time due to security issues or updates. Thus, I can use programs that work and are supported, i.e. GPG, Openssh, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to setup SSH keys and run the application from within an `ssh-agent` session, else you will be prompted for a password inside your application which might be harder to handle.

If you want to send files you also don't want the `ssh` binary; you most likely want to use `scp` for filetransfers. You can find scp in `/usr/bin/scp` if the package `openssh-client` is installed.

Comment: Found it, thanks. I am new to Linux so every wall I run into is a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh(1)` client executable is usually stored in `/usr/bin/ssh`. If your system does not have it installed already, run:

```
apt-get install openssh-client
```